# Combobox selected index not working when bound to String Array Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I am binding a string array resource to combobox ItemsSource. When I say SelectedIndex=0 it dosen't select anything. Please help.This is just part of the code.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<lib:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <converter:EnumToVisibilityConverter
            x:Key="EnumToVisibility"></converter:EnumToVisibilityConverter>

        <x:Array
            Type="{x:Type sys:String}"
            x:Key="ImageFormatsArray">
            <sys:String>Bmp</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Png</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Jpg</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Tif</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Gif</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </lib:MetroWindow.Resources>


<ComboBox
                    x:Name="CmbItems"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    ItemsSource="{StaticResource ImageFormatsArray}"
                    SelectedIndex="1"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedImageFormat}">

                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I think selectedIndex and selectedvalue  will not work togather. Try to put only selectedindex. If you want to use binding value then remove selectedindex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ComboBox
                x:Name="CmbItems"
                Width="100"
                Height="20"
                Background="Transparent"
                ItemsSource="{StaticResource ImageFormatsArray}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedImageFormat}">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```